# How to get UTF-8 format data through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, utf-8

Sorry if i am asking a silly question but i really need a solution for it.I am requesting for some data using ajax and the script is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
$url='http://localhost/path/to/the/php/script';
xmlhttp.open("GET",$url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is my php script

```
<?php 

$sqlurl='/path/to/my/file';

 if(file_exists($sqlurl))
            {
                $sqlitedata= file_get_contents($sqlurl);

       echo $sqlitedata;
            }
            else {

           echo 'the file is not available right now';
             } 
?>
```

Now the problem is that the data in my file is in the **UTF-8 format** but when i try to get it through ajax then what i get is a series of **question marks (??????)** . How can i request for the data through ajax in the same format in which it originally exists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

asuming your file is indeed a xml file, assuming the page making the request is utf8,

then before you `echo` anything in your php file :

```
<?php header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8"); ?>
```

for extra safety in your xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

edit you can do that as well :

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');
```

with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to use [utf8-encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) like,

```
echo utf8_encode($sqlitedata);
```

If you are using `jquery` then use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) with `contentType option` which is `default` like,

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
     $.ajax({
         type:"GET",
         url:"http://localhost/path/to/the/php/script",
         contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
         success: function(data){
             $("#myDiv").html(data);
         }
     });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

between head tag place this

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

If you use any query in your php page place this before your query

```
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
$result1 = mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```