# How to read API response format ajax

Tags: ajax, get, http-headers, postman

I have an API on one of our production manifacturing machines that has no documentation but the machine also has web interface. I open the interface on our internal IP that machine has - https://192.168.55.61/

So when I go to the section where I see the logs from the machines I go to console->network and I see the endpoint request performing:

[image]

When I use the URL and cookie in my Postman it works and returns an answer:

[image]

The problem is answer's format. Here I am not familiar how I should handle this and if I should put another Header for format. Is it possible to read this as you can see it returns something quite not readable. Also vendor of the machine is not willing to give me API documentation as he is insisting that something like API does not exist on machine (which is obviously a lie).

Is there any change to check something on console->network also to be able to help me to read the format?

EDIT:

Response Headers:
[image]

Comment: this is a duplicate i believe of this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19898977/how-to-get-utf-8-format-data-through-ajax

Comment: I don't see POSTMAN how can read it there. Tried to put Context-Type Header as text/xml but no results

Comment: Look at what the web interface does with the data.